# Carregar Combobox a partir de um List<>

Tags: c#, lista, combobox

Estou tentando carregar itens em um `ComboBox` a partir de um `List<>`, deu certo porém, posteriormente eu iria precisar pegar o código referente ao item selecionado, mas não esta dando certo.

O código para carregar o `ComboBox` é este:

```
private void frmCadProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.CadProdutoBD cadProdutoDB = new Model.CadProdutoBD();

    List<Control.CadCategoriaProduto> produto = new List<Control.CadCategoriaProduto>();
    produto = cadProdutoDB.carregaCategoriaProduto();

    foreach (Control.CadCategoriaProduto p in produto)
    {
        cmbCategoria.Items.Add(p.Categoria);
    }            
}
```

Vi que tem como fazer o seguinte:

```
cmbCategoria.DisplayMember = p.Categoria;
cmbCategoria.ValueMember = p.Categoria_id;
```

Porém não esta trazendo os itens desta forma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a propriedade [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx) do `Combobox`.

```
// ...
List<Control.CadCategoriaProduto> produto = new List<Control.CadCategoriaProduto>();

// ... 
cmbCategoria.DataSource = produto;
cmbCategoria.DisplayMember = "Categoria";
cmbCategoria.ValueMember = "Categoria_id";
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, era justamente isso que eu precisava. Muito Grato.